# StackOverflowError when running a JFrame in java

Tags: java, stack-overflow

I coded a JFrame (framePanel) in java but I'm getting a StackOverflowError when running it or running it from another class by instantiating an object of this class and calling the method 'create_ShowGUI()'.

Basically I want that when main() method is called, initComponents() method is called to initialize my components (sets radio buttons, groups them,adds Actionlistener to all radio buttons, creates a JPanel (menuFrame) & adds the buttons to it). After initComponents() finishes its job a JFrame is initialized, the JPanel is added to it & finally the frame is displayed.

Can you help me solve the error ?

**EDIT**: I created various apps but with NetBeans GUI Builder Tool. This is one of my first times that I'm trying to do it from scratch. Therefore excuse me if something isn't clear.

**EDIT**: Code updated with comments

**EDIT**: btw I coded with netbeans

Code starts here:

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;

/**
 *
 * @author jtech
 * @version 1.0.0
 * 
 * 'c' loop variable is initialized to 1
 * 'c1' loop variable is initialized to 0
 */
public class BankMainMenuFrame 
{      

//    public void BankMainMenuFrame()
//    {                
//        initComponents(); 
//        create_ShowGUI();
//    }

    private void initComponents()
    {
//        JRadioButton defaultOpt = new JRadioButton();
//        defaultOpt.setText(bankMainMenuOpts[0]);
//        defaultOpt.setMnemonic(0x30);
//        defaultOpt.setActionCommand("Default");
//        defaultOpt.setSelected(true);

        //initializes the first button aside the loop that initializes others (default)
        aJB[0] = new JRadioButton();
        aJB[0].setText(bankMainMenuOpts[0]);
        aJB[0].setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_0);
        aJB[0].setSelected(true);
        aJB[0].setActionCommand("Default");
        aJB[0].addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
            {
                aJBActionPerformed(evt, c);
            }
        });

        //the other buttons are initialized here
        while (c < bankMainMenuOpts.length)
        {
            aJB[c] = new JRadioButton();
            aJB[c].setText(bankMainMenuOpts[c]);
            aJB[c].setMnemonic((vK_nums + c));
            aJB[c].setActionCommand(aJB[c].getText());   
            groupRadioButtons.add(aJB[c]);

            aJB[c].addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
                {
                    aJBActionPerformed(evt, c);
                }
            });

            c++;
        }

        framePanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));

        //buttons will be added to the panel one by one
        while (c1 < bankMainMenuOpts.length)
        {
            framePanel.add(aJB[c1]);

            c1++;
        }

    }

//other methods go here; like 'private void defaultOptActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {}

    public void create_ShowGUI()
    {        
        initComponents();

        menuFrame = new JFrame("Bank Main Manu Program");
        menuFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        menuFrame.add(framePanel); //framePanel is added to menuFrame
        menuFrame.setContentPane(new Container());
        menuFrame.pack();
        menuFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void aJBActionPerformed(ActionEvent e, int optionNum)
    {
      //  aCA_MainMenuFrame.executeSelectedMenuOption(); 
        //calls a method which is in another class & that class isn't posted here due to its large 
       //amount of code         
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

                //instance of this class is created to call create_ShowGUI() method
                new BankMainMenuFrame().create_ShowGUI();

    }

    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="variables decrlarations">
    private static char vK_nums = 0x30;
    private static int c = 1, c1 = 0;
    private static String[] bankMainMenuOpts = {"Select an option..",     //[0] (pre-selected)
        "Deposit Money",                                                  //[1]
        "Withdraw Money",                                                 //[2]
        "Display Balance",                                                //[3]
        "Exit Bank Account Program"};                                     //[4]

    private static JFrame menuFrame = null;
    private static JPanel framePanel = null;
    private static JRadioButton[] aJB = new JRadioButton[5];
    private static ButtonGroup groupRadioButtons = new ButtonGroup();

    //</editor-fold>   
}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) When I comment out the parts that do not compile, I get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: I never got that exception. I re-posted the code

Comment: Post an ***SSCCE.***  That code does not *compile* without `CheckingAccount`!

Comment: sorry remove that stament 'CheckingAccount aCA_MainMenuFrame = new CheckingAccount(); '

Comment: Don't apologize or tell me what to edit.  Post an ***SSCCE***.

Comment: Ok let me give the other classes

Comment: Did I say 'give the other classes'?  *Read* the SSCCE document.

Comment: Can you tell me how? Never used it before

Comment: I did tell you how, in the SSCCE document.  What part(s) of it do you not understand?

Comment: Better if you download the project: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/28wv5cwsx4bojdr/lHsz4KnT80

Comment: Thanks for being so helpful when someone doesn't understand

Comment: I tried to help you 5 times (6 if you count writing/hosting the SSCCE document) but it seems you cannot be helped, at least not by me.

Comment: @Joseph - Andrew linked to http://sscce.org/ in his first comment in an attempt to get a 'Short, Self Contained, Correct Example' - the idea being to try simplifying your code down to a much smaller example that reproduces the problem - examples in this format make it much easier for us to identify the issue quickly/accurately and help resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stack overflow seems to be corrected.
Remain two errors;

```
    while (c < bankMainMenuOpts.length) { //ERROR was <=

   //ERROR menuFrame.setContentPane(new Container());
```

Comment: I got it running. Copy the code from your question. Check that `public void BankMainMenuFrame()` is commented out (there is recursion).

Comment: Now it works but nothing is being displayed: see updated code above. Thanks

Comment: Now remove `menuFrame.setContentPane(new Container());` as this removes the panel. JFrame.add is a short-cut for JFrame.getContentPane().add.

Comment: Thanks, it now works :). I heard that 'menuFrame.setContentPane(new Container());' is the same like add, but I get confused what actually the content pane of the JFrame is. If I'm not mistaken it's just the area where I can drop my components, right?

Another query if you don't mind: When should I program like the code above & when I should use instead 'extend' & 'implements' (I'm novice in inheritance for now, only know how to use 'extend' which inherits another class's objects & fields).

Comment: Once JFrame was rewritten and a contentPane added. No longer one actually added to the JFrame, but to the `getContentPane()`. To keep compatibility, `JFrame.add` does internally call `getContentPame().add`. `setContentPane` is not needed, as there is a default component.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a circular dependency on line 135 of BankMainMenuFrame.
I suspect the constructor is doing the init in a loop.